# How to retain SKSpriteNode velocity after collision with physicsBody?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, velocity, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

In my game i don't want to decrease velocity of my `SKSpriteNode` after collision with any `physicsBody`.

Currently velocity of my `SKSpriteNode` is decresing very much after collision with `physicsBody`.

**What did i tried :**

I tried to get `velocity` in
 `-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime` method & i provide it to my `SKSpriteNode` in below method :

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
```

But it doesn't make any difference.

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restitution basically equates to an object's "bounciness".

Sprite Kit Physicsbody Restitution is defined as

Property describing how much energy a body retains when it bounces off of another body, basically a fancy way of saying "bounciness"" -IOS Games by Tutorials*

So make  `self.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;`

Refer [Restitution](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/restitution)